# React conditional re-rerender of an array based on filter

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I’m running into an error that I could use some help on

Basically, I have a react app that is executing an HTTP call, receiving an array of data, and saving that into a state variable called ‘tasks’. Each object in that array has a key called ‘completed’. I also have a checkbox on the page called ‘Show All’ that toggles another state variable called showAll. The idea is by default all tasks should be shown however if a user toggles this checkbox, only the incomplete tasks (completed==false) should be shown. I can get all tasks to display but can’t get the conditional render to work based on the checkbox click

Here’s how I’m implementing this. I have the HTTP call executed on the page load using a useEffect hook and available to be called as a function from other change handlers (edits etc.)

Before I call the main return function in a functional component, I’m executing a conditional to check the status of ’ShowAll’ and filter the array if it's false. This is resulting in too many re-render errors. Any suggestions on how to fix it?

See simplified Code Below

```
const MainPage = () => {


    const [tasks, setTasks] = useState([]); //tasks
    const [showAll, setShowAll] = useState(true);  //this is state for the checkbox (show all or just incomplete)

    useEffect( ()=> {
        axios.get('api/tasks/')
            .then( response => {   //this is the chained API call
                setTasks(response.data.tasks); 
            })
            .catch(err => {
                console.log('error');
            })
        
    }, []);

    const fetchItems = (cat_id) => {  
        axios.get('/api/tasks/')
        .then( response => {
                setTasks(response.data.tasks);
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log('error');
        })
    }; 


    //change the checkbox state
    const handleCheckboxChange = (e) => {
        setShowAll(!showAll)
        console.log('Checkbox: ', showAll)
    };

    
    //this part updates the tasks to be filtered down to just the incomplete ones based on the checkbox value
    if (showAll === false) {
        setTasks(tasks.filter(v => v['completed']===false)); //only show incomplete tasks
    }
    

    return (
        <div>
           
           <label className="checkb">
                <input 
                name="show_all"
                id="show_all"
                type="checkbox"
                checked={showAll}
                onChange={handleCheckboxChange}
                /> Show all
            </label>

            <br/>
            { tasks && tasks.map((task, index) => {
                return (
                    <div key={index} className="task-wrapper flex-wrapper">
                    
                        <div > 
                                { task.completed === false ? (
                                <span> {index +1}. {task.task_description} </span> ) : 
                                (<strike> {index +1}. {task.task_description} </strike>)  }                               
                        </div>
                        
                        <div>
                            <button 
                                onClick={()=> modalClick(task)}
                                className="btn btn-sm btn-outline-warning">Edit</button>
                            <span> &nbsp;  </span>
                        
                            
                        </div>
                    </div>
                )
                })}
                
         
        </div>
    );

};

export default MainPage;
```

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Two things to fix:

Use the checked property on `event.target` to update the state:

```
const handleCheckboxChange = ({target: { checked }}) => {
  setShowAll(checked)
};
```

Filter as you want but don't update the state right before returning the JSX as that would trigger a rerender and start an infinite loop:

```
let filteredTasks = tasks;

if (!showAll) {
      filteredTasks = tasks?.filter(v => !v.completed));
}
```

and in the JSX:

`{ tasks && tasks.map` should be `{filteredTasks?.map(...`

Comment: This shall suffice but why not manipulate the main array right after setShowAll changing showAll state ?

Comment: The first part is not necessary, he can use the previous value to toggle the showAll. but the 2nd part is the correct answer. It would be great if you can explain why he was wrong using `setTasks`...

Comment: @emre-ozgun if you filter inside `handleCheckboxChange`, it is impossible to restore the unfiltered array

Comment: @gilamran it is always better to rely on the event to update the value when implementing a controlled input.

Comment: I understand @RameshReddy so I'd have to define another state to hold filtered values that would be possible with my approach correct ? and then conditionally render that showAll ? filteredMap : mainMap kinda...

Comment: @RameshReddy, you are correct but this is not the problem he's trying to solve.
@emre-ozgun, I would not call the `filteredMap` a state, it's just a variable that helps you render the requested view.

Comment: @emre-ozgun Yes, that approach works too.

Comment: @gilamran I know that's not the main issue but, there's nothing wrong with suggesting improvements.

Comment: so, maybe mention that it's not related to the problem (bug) that he presented. just a nice to have (I would add that suggestion at the end of your anwer)

Comment: @gilamran my solution creates another state (that is filteredArr) different from rameshreddy's example I was suggesting creating a different state to hold filtered values so that it can be set whenever setShowAll changes showAll state and returning with ternary operator. ramesreddy pointed out filtering the main state right away would certainly result in the loss of data...

Answer (score 0):

use e.target.value and useEffect :

```
      //change the checkbox state
    const handleCheckboxChange = (e) => {
        setShowAll(e.target.checked)
        console.log('Checkbox: ', showAll)
 if (!e.target.checked) {
let list =tasks.filter(v => v.completed===false);
        setTasks(list ); //only show incomplete tasks
    }
    };



or

      //change the checkbox state
        const handleCheckboxChange = (e) => {
            setShowAll(e.target.checked)
            console.log('Checkbox: ', showAll)
   
        };

useEffect(()=>{
  if (showAll === false) {
    let list =tasks.filter(v => v.completed===false);
            setTasks(list ); //only show incomplete tasks
        }
},[showAll])
```

Comment: this will filter the tasks but when the checkbox gets checked again, there's no way to restore all tasks

Comment: try to use e.target.checked I think the problem is there